# General Link Field not populating the exisitng external link while editing

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-speak-ui

I am trying to edit the external link in a General link field of sitecore but its not populating the existing field value during editing by clicking the insert the existing link.

I am using sitecore 7.1 is this a sitecore bug.

Please let me know if anyone knows about this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is a known issue with Sitecore 7.x versions.

There is a workaround:
https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/disable-sitecore-speak-dialogs/

And if you like to get your hands dirty:
http://www.reinoudvandalen.nl/blog/fixing-sitecore-7-internal-link-with-speak/